# AWS security group equivalent in Digital Ocean

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, digital-ocean, real-time-multiplayer

I am working on a multiplayer game and I want to connect players which are in the same network.I have to achieve this using digital Ocean as we do it in AWS security group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be [Cloud Firewalls](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/networking/firewalls/overview/). In your droplet, you'll see the Firewall section in the Networking tab

Comment: I tried adding a rule in Firewall to allow only one IP but still, it is publically accessible

Answer (score 0):

There is concept of private IP feature ,try using that private IP and see if it solves

Comment: I go through the Private IP feature of Digital Ocean Networking but its not give me expected result